# Recursive traversal of 2d array to find unique paths

Tags: arrays, algorithm, recursion

I need to traverse a 2D-Array of 0's (which represent open pathways) and 1's which represent walls. I have to calculate the number of unique paths from (0,0) to (N-1,N-1) of an NxN Grid. I have written a recursive method to do this however i cannot figure out why the traversal part of my method (i.e the straight, left and right movements) are not working as expected:

```
    public static void TraversePath(int [][] Grid, boolean[][] isTraversed, int column, int row) {
    if(row < 0 || column < 0 || row > Grid[0].length || column > Grid[0].length )
        return; // if you go out of bounds
    if(isTraversed[column][row] == true)
        return; // if you have already been to the point
    if(Grid[column][row]==1) {
        isTraversed[column][row] = true; // if the current point is a wall mark it as traversed
        return;
    }
    if(Grid[column][row]!=1 && (row == Grid[0].length-1 && column == Grid[0].length-1)) { //if you get to an endpoint that isn't a wall
        uniquePaths++; //counter that tallys the unique paths
        isTraversed[column][row] = true;
        return;
    }

    TraversePath(Grid,column,row+1);//Straight
    TraversePath(Grid,column-1, row);//Left
    TraversePath(Grid,column+1, row);//Right

}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [][]Grid = new int[][]
            {
        {0,1,1,0},
        {0,0,1,0},
        {0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,1,0}
            };
    boolean[][] isTraversed = new boolean[Grid.length][Grid.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < Grid.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j< Grid.length; j++)
            isTraversed[i][j] = false;
    }
    TraversePath(Grid,isTraversed,0,0);
    System.out.println(uniquePaths);

}
```

I keep getting a StackOverFlow error (hey, sounds familiar) when I run this code. I figure it probably has something to do with how I am marking the edges as visited in the isTraversed boolean graph but I am not sure. Any help would be super appreciated.

This is the main method that I'm using to test the array, it's a simple 4x4 grid with 2 unique paths to (3,3).

Comment: can be helpful... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46763964/count-all-path-in-a-binary-matrix

Comment: You're checking `Grid[column][row] == 1`, however it's never assigned value 1.

Comment: Just verifying - you have written code that you can travel in three directions, viz. straight, left and right. All the variations I have seen of this question allow traveling only right (or left) and down (or up).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Stack Overflow` Error is caused by the fact that you can continuously move left then right again. Assuming that you could only move in the positive directions, you could make a very simple recursive function using dynamic programing to prevent you from getting a `Stack Overflow` error.

```
public static int possiblePaths(int[][] grid, int x,int y,int [][] dp){
    if(x<0||x>=grid.length||y<0||y>=grid[0].length)
        return 0;
    if(dp[x][y]==-1){
        dp[x][y]=possiblePaths(grid,x+1,y,dp)+possiblePaths(grid,x,y+1,dp);
    }
    return dp[x][y];
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [][]Grid = new int[][]
            {
        {0,1,1,0},
        {0,0,1,0},
        {0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,1,0}
            };
    int [][] dp = new int[Grid.length][Grid[0].length];
    for(int i = 0; i < Grid.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j< Grid[0].length; j++)
            if(Grid[i][j]==1)
                dp[i][j]=0;
            else
                dp[i][j]=-1;
    }
    dp[Grid.length-1][Grid[0].length-1]=0;
    System.out.println(possiblePaths(Grid,0,0,dp));

}
```

What this basically states that the amount of ways to get from `(x,y)` to the end is the sum of # of paths from `(x+1,y)` and # of paths from `(x,y+1)` and remembers these numbers in the dp (Dynamic Programing) array so you do not need to recalculate them. In the dp array, the cells where there are walls are set to 0 because there are 0 ways to get to the end from the wall.

Comment: While you are using DP, in the question OP has written code to allow traveling in three directions (straight, right and left). Using DP you are traveling in only two directions.

Comment: Like I stated, if you were able to travel in three directions, there would be an infinite amount of paths as you could repeatedly go left and right a different amount of times. This is also the most likely cause of the Stack Overflow error. Therefore, I am assuming that that was a misinterpretation of the question.

Comment: My mistake. Instead of reading through the entire answer I just saw your DP oriented code and commented.

Comment: hey thank you so much this was such a simple elegant solution to the problem, i wish i was able to think more recursively. Out of curiosity what would be the time complexity for an algorithm like this? I’ve never thought of time complexity in terms of each new recursive stack

Comment: So generally this would be O(2^n) if there was no memoisation aka. dynamic programing. However, with the dynamic programing the run time is O(n^2) as you only need to calculate the number of paths for each point once and then store it for later use.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of errors in this code, but the main problem is that you do not set `isTraversed[column][row] = true` if you just make a normal step without running into any of the if-statements.

Another big problem is, that the `isTraversed` array is shared across different search paths. This means that a grid-field visited in one branch of the iteration cannot be visited in another branch. Ultimately, your result will thus be always at most 1. In order to avoid this you could make a deep copy of `isTraversed` just before you enter the next iteration step.

```
boolean[][] isTraversedCopy = new boolean[isTraversed.length][isTraversed[0].length];
for(int i=0; i<isTraversed.length; i++)
      for(int j=0; j<isTraversed[i].length; j++)
          isTraversedCopy[i][j]=isTraversed[i][j];

TraversePath(Grid,isTraversedCopy, column,row+1);//Straight
TraversePath(Grid,isTraversedCopy, column-1, row);//Left
TraversePath(Grid,isTraversedCopy, column+1, row);//Right
```

Other problems are:

- `TraversePath(Grid,column,row+1);//Straight` and the following lines are missing an argument (isTraversed)
- in the first if-statement it should be 
  `if(row < 0 || column < 0 || row >= Grid[0].length || column >= Grid[0].length)`
- Why is there no possibility to move to the bottom?
- Optional but this will make readability of your code easier: You should change row and column to make it consistent to your representation of the gridworld and with the normal use of 2d-arrays. Additionally, your definition of straight, left, right is a bit confusing and does not fit to the grid definition.